# Creating a new column by filing in with corresponding headers in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on a multi-segmented .txt file. Each segment has header information and contains a list of longitudes and latitudes in two columns. I want to get rid of these headers after copying them into the corresponding blocks as a third column. For example,

Original File:

```
Marine Rocks
-122.18568824 38.75846893
```

Output File:

```
-122.18568824 38.75846893 Marine Rocks
```

Here's an image showing how the file actually looks:

[image: Screen capture showing text file]

Answer (score 0):

In short: read in the whole file into a datastructure, write it out in your new format.

You'll want the `csv` module.